# What is the natural aspect ratio of a 12 column grid?

Tags: page-layout, grids, layout

If I have a 12 column grid, what's the natural aspect ratio for items in the grid?

Or, more specifically, I'm using 3 content-columns - each 4 grid-columns wide.  Is there a natural height of images in my columns, and if so what is it?

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: It depends on what your content is and what style you're going for. AFAIK this question is quite (if not fully) opinion based as is

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is no "natural" height of images. But one common practice is to make the height a multiple to the width (or half, or a third), or in other words; in [ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio).

Which proportion system you choose is again a case to case decision and a mater of opinion.